# Algorithm/Strategy or Data structure to capture priorities sub priorities in an app

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, data-modeling

I am working on a CMS that is starting to evolve a bit.

We started off with content that had the following priorities ( columnn in the db on the content table): HIGH MED LOW.  Data was fetched by priority HIGH being on top etc.

Now after a few months a need has risen to have sub priorities:  HIGH [ high, med , low ], MED [high, med, low ] etc.

I have a test branch with a sub-priority column in the db. So fetch by priority now brings back HIGH(high) HIGH(med) HIGH(low) first.   Wondering is there a better way to do this that I not seeing.

There is a rails app.

Comment: Maybe you'll add another category later HIGH --> HIGH --> HIGH then how you'll try to manage? Then you may expand more. How about using numbers for priority? 1 being the highest of all and maybe the smallest integer being the lowest of priorities.

Answer (score 2):

If priority is not a small (3) set of values, and nuances between the priorities is necessary, then it is a larger enumerable set.

How large you make this set is up to you, but it is likely easier to make it very large (1 .. 1024 for example), but then you have to discipline the users to not put everything at max priority anyways. This is often a problem with bug trackers where the business sets the only priority (high, medium, low), everything is high.  Then they add critical, and everything is critical or high.

Consider trying to measure multiple metrics at once to determine the priority.  While bug tracker focused - [Improving Bug Triage with User Pain](http://www.lostgarden.com/2008/05/improving-bug-triage-with-user-pain.html) takes multiple metrics that are orthogonal to each other:

- Type of bug (crash - documentation)
- Priority of bug (breaking build - nuisance)
- Likelihood of hitting the bug (everyone hitting it - one person hitting it)

Score each of these on a 1 .. n scale, multiply them together and divide by the max.  This gives a number between 100 and 1.  And there is your priority.

For a CMS, one could consider such metrics as:

- Importance of article (this is very important - just a notification)
- Visibility of article (this goes on the front page - this goes to the back page)
- etc...

Comment: Excellent, Thanks Michael. Your description is correct, I am going to work with our product guys to come up with a (hopefully) simple scoring system that will make the setting of priority a calculation and hopefully I can simply sort by score.